# Select from data, then copy to system clipboard and paste into another program

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, I have certain names of items linked to certain barcode numbers (for example item1 00335578). Let's say these are stored in 2 columns in a spreadsheet.

On another spreadsheet I want to have a search box with autocomplete functions. For example I have two items in the database - item1 and house2. When the user starts typing "it", the possible matches (in the current scenario item1) should popup (just like in Google search) and the user can click on them.

Next to this field there will be a button - "Copy". By clicking on it will copy **the barcode** of the corresponding item that we searched for (NOT THE NAME). Preferably this will also paste it into another program that is currently open (I would be happy for suggestions on that).

For the sake of simplicity I can make 2 compromises in the design, if you guys think that this is too complicated, or that the implementation of such behaviour is an obvious overkill:

1. The search box, can be a dropdown menu, instead of a field with autocompletion features
2. The "Copy Button" can simply copy the barcode number, and leave the user to paste it in the other open program.

This has to be done in excel, I hope you can help-out. I need a guidance on how to approach this problem, I do not expect full solutions (though, I gotta admit, it would be helpful :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to get you started. The user will have to manually paste the data.

[image]

### 1 - Data Validation

Select the cell and then go to **Data** > **Data Validation**. Set the **Source** to the list of items you wish to include.

[image]

In the example above, I made use of [named ranges](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/named-ranges.htm) with *items* referencing the first column of:

[image]

### 2 - Shape with assigned macro

The "button" in the first image is just a shape with an assigned macro which **(1)** takes name of the item selected, **(2)** looks its barcode up from the sample source data and then **(3)** sends the barcode to the clipboard for the user's perusal.

Here's the code I used. Just change it to suit your needs (*item* refers to cell B2 in my example and *products* refers to the sample source data):

```
Sub Get_Barcode()
    Dim objData As New DataObject
    Dim barcode As String
    barcode = Application.VLookup(Range("item"), Range("products"), 2, False)
    objData.SetText barcode
    objData.PutInClipboard
    MsgBox "Barcode " & barcode & " copied to clipboard"
End Sub
```

When used:

[image]

<sub>*You may need to [add a reference](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-add-vba-reference-microsoft-forms-2-0-object-library-t3365334.html) to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library for this code to work. On the VBA editor, go to **Tools** > **References** > **Browse** and check it there. If it's not listed, you may need to click **Browse** and manually add it. On my laptop, it's on  `C:\Windows\System32\FM20.DLL`.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could enhance  the above macro by directly sending the data to the external application with the `Application.SendKeys` Method, instead of placing it into the clipboard.

Comment: Sounds really nice, I'll look into it.